Issues with downloading NCBI database
I am trying to download the NCBI database to a remote server using R:
library("taxizedb")

db_download_ncbi()

But I end up with this error message:

Error in curl::curl_download(db_url, db_path_file, quiet = TRUE)
Timeout was reached [ftp.ncbi.nih.gov]: Connection timeout after 10002 ms

I've tried to increase the timeout period, but I still get the exact same error :(

Sounds like an issue with ftp.ncbi.nih.gov, perhaps it was temporarily down.
Though, what do you mean by "to a remote server" ? Does it work on your local system but not with some remote R instance? Does downloading with curl, to mimic db_download_ncbi(), work for you - curl::curl_download("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/taxonomy/taxdmp.zip", "taxdmp.zip", quiet = FALSE) ?
